# Suspending another thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

In a program I'm developing, I have two primary threads: the UI thread and a background thread that interfaces with hardware. On the form during the run, I have a pause button that should stop the test until a resume button is clicked. Functionally this means that I want to use the UI thread to suspend the hardware thread, and since `Thread.Suspend` is deprecated, I'm trying to avoid that.

I tried used an `AutoResetEvent`, which unfortunately resulted in the UI thread suspending itself, and then locking up the hardware thread when it tried to send a UI update request.

Is there a good way to use one thread to suspend another in VB.NET at any point in execution?

---

As an aside, I've already looked at [Suspend a thread from another thread in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579527/suspend-a-thread-from-another-thread-in-vb-net), and while the question was similar, the answers ended up discussing essentially the inverse situation from what I'm trying to do.

---

My code is set up so that the multithreading actually occurs through a multithreaded object, and the form makes a call to an asynchronous `Run` routine within that object. I'll try to provide the most relevant information, but if there are other parts of the code you'd like to see, let me know and I can add them.

In `frmRun`

```
'Multithreaded object copied from global to local context
Private currentprofile as MTProfile = Main.testprofile  

'Button click handler to start the run
Private Sub btnRunTest_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRunTest.Click
    currentprofile.RunAsync()
End Sub
```

In `MTProfile`

```
'Asynchronous call to run subroutine
'_thread1 is a member of the MTProfile class
Public Sub RunAsync()
    _thread1 = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Run)
    _thread1.IsBackground = True
    _thread1.Start()
End Sub

'Run subroutine
Public Sub Run()
    For i As Integer = 0 To _profile.Count - 1
        'Get information for the action in the profile and carry that action out
        'Actions can last anywhere from 50 s to over 10 minutes
    Next
End Sub
```

---

My current thought as to getting the code to pause is to have clicking the pause button on the form raise an event that is caught by the object and asks `_thread1` to pause. The two main concerns I have with that are what function I can use to actually get the thread to pause and how to set up the event trigger so that it still allows encapsulation of the class.

---

As to why I think this question is not a duplicate of [Pause/Resume loop in Background worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359058/pause-resume-loop-in-background-worker), there are two main reasons. The most important is that I want to be able to suspend my process at any time rather than after each loop iteration, which I don't think I could do using that solution without putting a `WaitOne` command after every command in my loop. The second, which I think matters much less, is that I'm manipulating my thread directly rather than using a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Without seeing your code, your question is impossible to answer. For instance, why did manipulating a `AutoResetEvent` object "suspend" the UI thread?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It blocked (probably should have used the proper terminology) the UI thread because I did it wrong. Thinking back on it, having the UI thread raise an event and run into a `WaitOne` command was just stupid on my part.

Comment: @Aliden: "I want to be able to suspend my process *(you probably meant thread)* at any time rather than after each loop iteration". You can't - plain and simple. The pausing needs to be cooperative, and you were sort of heading down the right path with the `AutoResetEvent` although I'm surprised that you went for that as opposed to `ManualResetEvent`. What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I did mean thread; my mistake. I was using `AutoResetEvent` instead of `ManualResetEvent` because of a lack of experience. I'm targeting .NET 2.0. Why do you say I can't pause it anywhere? Let's say, for the sake of argument, that I used a `ManualResetEvent` and put a `WaitOne` statement after every line in the `Run` function. Wouldn't that make it so I could block the thread anywhere I could edit my code?

Comment: @Aliden, technically yes, but that still does not constitute "suspending the thread at any time". For example, if you make a synchronous call inside your loop, which takes (as per your code comments) between 50s and 10 minutes, your `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne` will not be hit until that synchronous work is fully done, which in some cases can take a long time. If you can't integrate the wait handle into your low-level code which interfaces with the hardware your ability to pause the method's execution up the call chain will be limited due to the presence of those long-running operations.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy You're absolutely right; it's not. But it may be the closest I can manage. As far as the other options I have, from what I understand, `Suspend` actually stops a thread where it is, and `Resume` picks it up. Can you explain to me why (other than the fact they're deprecated) it's a bad idea to use those functions?